# Android charts: to use webview/JS or to go native

Tags: android, charts, visualization

We are going to build a android library which will provide a API for developers to build applications which can embed certain charts easily (the charts would display specific contents particular to the API).

Since there are no charting libraries that are dominant in the market, what library would be ideal for this. Some of the chart types need to be developed for this that are currently not supported by any native libraries( like heatmaps). Keeping this in mind would you guys advice going in for a native lib or with webview embedded HTML/JS.

The problem with webview is that you cannot package assets(html/js) on a library project like resources. So its again a additional step for the developers using the library to copy the assets to the project.

Additional Info:

My API should allow the developer to easily embed a chart. Something like

```
    <org.example.customPieChart
        android:id="@+id=chart"
        android:width="150dip"
        android:height="150dip"
        />
```

And the API should take care of everything else. Only if the developer wants to change color, customize the stuff then possibly he will use the other parts of the API and do that.

Answer (score 1):

I have used aChartEngine Library for the chart and its working fine. So I am suggesting you aChartEngine.